# Mongoose: Exclude objects from results based on another model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a `User` and `Group` model, groups have users, like

```js
var GroupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

How would I query to get all the Users but exclude the ones that are on 
`Group.users`, I'm already doing this by querying first `Group` then manually filtering against all `users`

```js
        var groupP = Group.findById(group_id).populate('users');
        var userP = User.find();

        Promise.props({
            group: groupPromise.exec(),
            users: usersPromise.exec()
        })
        .then(function (result) {
        //this gives the expected result but I'm looking for a more straight forward mongoose only solution if possible
          var users = differenceWith(result.users, result.group.users, (a, b) => { return a._id.toString() == b._id.toString()});
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query.

```
var groupP = Group.findById(group_id);
var userP = User.find({_id:{$nin:groupP.users}});
```

Comment: this was the way to go, I guess there's no way to make the query in one go. thanks